# How to know Android GPU Usage?

Tags: android, gpu

How do I check GPU usage of Android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within the device, I don't know of anything that can do this. From a development standpoint, devices with Qualcomm GPUs can use their profiler. https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/gaming-graphics-optimization-adreno/tools-and-resources